# Could not parse the remainder: '('static', filename='main.png')' from 'url_for('static', filename='main.png')'

Tags: python, html, django

I am a `django` beginner and I am trying to render a `html` page. I already have a test html page and URL to test this out.

Upon hitting the URL, following error is encountered:

`Could not parse the remainder: '('static', filename='main.png')' from 'url_for('static', filename='main.png')'`

Complete Trace:

```
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/xxxxx
Django Version:    3.0.2
Exception Type:    TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Could not parse the remainder: '('static', filename='main.png')' from 'url_for('static', filename='main.png')'
Exception Location:    F:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py in __init__, line 662
Python Executable:    F:\Anaconda\python.exe
Python Version:    3.7.0
```

I have tried using single & double quotes but it still doesn't work. kind of stuck at this point.

Any comments/suggestions/hints/links-to-guides are appreciated.

Comment: And will you show the template code?

Comment: @charnel thanks for quick reply, template code is like -     .bg-image {
      background-image: url("{{url_for('static', filename='main.png')}}");
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
    }

Comment: That's incorrect syntax for templates. Check answer below - it seems to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/). You have to make sure you load static in the template with `{% load static %}` and then you can just get django to generate the link to the file within the template by using `{% static "static/path.ext" %}`

So you would change you file to:

```
.bg-image {
    background-image: url("{% static "main.png" %}");
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Just remember to put `{% load static %}` at the top of the file.